# Php header redirection issue with dynamic php value

Tags: post, header

header("location:view_appointment.php?apid=".$_REQUEST["apid"]."");
exit();

I don't know y the above header function isn't working

Comment: 1. You need to specify what you mean by "isn't working". Do you get a error message? 
2. What is in REQUEST["apid"], try to echo it to see the value

Comment: the page isnt redirecting..i am getting the apid, its an integer value

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for header() not working right in PHP, is data being sent before the header call. Depending on your PHP settings this should show a warning:
"PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent ...".

The other reason might be that the output from $_REQUEST["apid"] is in some way making it not work, tho I can't think how.

The PHP code look right, so I can't think of anything else that might make it not work.

Try setting

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

in your php file.

Also, make absolutely sure nothing is sent before your header() call, no echo or print.

Nothing before the "< ?php", not even a space or line.